# Ruler color in Illustrator CC

Tags: adobe-illustrator

Is there a way to make the rulers in Illustrator CC a different color? As I move the tools around the artboard, I can barely see their location on the ruler.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. i changed the color of the user interface.